# Include node module as a file to inject

Tags: sails.js

I want to include `/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js` into the client side in Sails v0.11.

I've tried including it into the pipeline as such:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

 // Load sails.io before everything else
 'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

 /* INCLUDE NODE MODULE */
 '/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',

 // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
 'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

 // All of the rest of your client-side js files
 // will be injected here in no particular order.
 'js/**/*.js',

 // Use the "exclude" operator to ignore files
 // '!js/ignore/these/files/*.js'
];
```

Is this possible? I don't really want to use bower or a CDN, I would like to install/update the dependency via npm.

Comment: Showing the layout of your file structure would make this a much easier question to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be to leave the `pipeline.js` file alone and just make a symlink inside of `assets/js` pointing to the file you want, e.g.:

```
ln -s ../../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js assets/js/es6-shim.min.js
```

Next time you run `sails lift`, Grunt will see the new Javascript file in your `assets/js` folder and process it with the rest.

If this is for some reason not an option, you'll need to add a new subtask to the `tasks/copy.js` Grunt task:

```
    dev_es6: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js'],
            dest: '.tmp/public/js'
        }]
    }
```

and then add that to the `compileAssets` task in `tasks/register/compileAssets`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'jst:dev',
        'less:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'copy:dev_es6', // <-- adding our new subtask
        'coffee:dev'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: in copy.js, you should include `flatten: true` or the file's URL will be `http://example.com/js/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js`